# Blazor Server Side - MainLayout cascading parameter always NULL in Index

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a class of NewStuff.cs, and am attempting to send it down from my MainLayout into all of my other components, beginning with the Index.razor component. But on the Index side, it keeps coming up NULL. I have debugged my class variable to make sure that it is not null and has data on the MainLayout.razor component.

My partial code:

```
<div class="page">
    <main>
        <div style="height:200px;border-bottom-style:solid;background-color:steelblue">
        </div>
        <div>
            <NavMenu />
        </div>
        <CascadingValue Value="@newStuff">
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
        </CascadingValue>
    </main>
</div>

@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private NewStuff newStuff { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ///Code to populate newStuff to ensure that it isn't null.
    }
}
```

And my relevant, partial code on the index side:

```
@code{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter]
    private NewStuff newStuff { get; set; }
    private String username { get; set; }
    private TennantInfoDTO tennantInfo { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationState;
        username = authState.User.Identity.Name;
        tennantInfo = await _tennantInfoRepository.Get(newStuff);
    }

}
```

It is here while debugging the parameter that I find it is now null, and the values that were previously there have disappeared. Have I overlooked something in my code when dealing with cascading parameters in Blazor?

Update -- added App.razor:

```
@using App_Database.Data;

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <LoginRedirect/>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>


@code{

}
```

Comment: What does App.razor look like?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have added my code for App.razor.

Comment: Is it Net7.0. ?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I am currently using Net 6.0 I believe.

Comment: While this is probably wrong in the Layout `[CascadingParameter] private NewStuff newStuff { get; set; } = new();`, your code should work as you've shown.  I've tested it.  So there must be something you are not showing.
`

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Nothing that I can find. On the index and login components, the syntax is the same: `[CascadingParameter]
private MarathonNOC marathonNOC { get; set; }`. Would it have anything to do with the OnInitializedAsync method?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Please see my answer. I moved the `<CascadingValue Value="@marathonNOC">` and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have fixed the issue.

I moved my cascading parameter in the MainLayout.razor outside of the `<div class="page">`.

This appears to have worked:

```
<CascadingValue Value="@newStuff">
<div class="page">
    <main>
        <div style="height:200px;border-bottom-style:solid;background-color:steelblue">
        </div>
        <div>
            <NavMenu />
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
</CascadingValue>
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but it works.  Note that if it doesn't change after the initial page render set it as IsFixed to stop unnecessary rendering.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I may have spoken too soon -- it appears to be passing through correctly now for my login page, but after successfully logging in (and going to the index page), the parameter is now null again.

Comment: I thought you would get bitten again at some point.  I go back to "So there must be something you are not showing.".

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis For my understanding, is the class variable that is in MainLayout rendered and repopulated only at the beginning of the building of the app? Or does it start over as I navigate to each separate component? While debugging, I noticed that it only hit that code once.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  Though the login page is probably statically rendered.  There's nothing in the code in your question to indicate where the problem is.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I'm curious, would the cascading parameter being utilized in the OnInitializedAsync() method within Index.razor have anything to do with it? My understanding is that it would already be populated at that point and therefore safe to use.

Comment: All `Parameters` are set at the beginning of `SetParametersAsync`, before `OnInitialized{Async}` and `OnParametersSet{Async}`.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I ran another test -- it does appear to be null within OnInitializedAsync(). However, once the page has finished rendering and everything is complete, the value is no longer null (this is what's occurring on the login page). This throws me for a loop as I thought the parameters were already set.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on the logic, but ?I guarantee what's happening is logical.  Is there any way you can produce a [MRE].  With that I can give you an explanation.  without it, I don't think I can..